# How to debug Phantom JS / Poltergeist Issues after upgrade to OS X 10.11

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, cucumber, capybara, poltergeist

Not sure if this is related to my upgrade to El Capitan but all of a sudden my Feature and Integration tests have started to fail.

My cucumber tests are failing with:

```
Capybara::Driver::Base#evaluate_script (Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError)
```

and my features fail with:

```
Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError
```

I appreciate phantomjs is no longer supported with `homebrew` so I installed it with `npm install -g phantomjs`. I also tried installing phantomjs2 but that just hangs during the install.

Is there an easy way to verify that my phantomjs is installed correctly for a start? Do I need to persist and get phantomjs2 installed?

Capybara and poltergeist versions are:

```
   capybara (2.4.4)
   capybara-mechanize (1.4.0)
   capybara-screenshot (1.0.11)
   poltergeist (1.7.0)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do not use binary phantomjs that is ready to use from there: http://phantomjs.org/download.html ?

Comment: Thanks, tried that still no luck with original problem